# How do I override the jQuery.ajaxTransport function?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I need to change the function jQuery.ajaxTransport  to make it function correctly with BlackBerry OS5. I have the code worked out, but I want a clever way to override the function without changing the JQuery framework

THanks,

Comment: Do you have any code? What do you mean by "make it function correctly"?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the concept you are desiring to employ is called [Monkey Patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).

Include the jQuery file, then *immediately* (before using jQuery) include your script which does this:

```
( function( global )
{
  if( global.jQuery )
  {
    global.jQuery.ajaxTransport = function( transports )
    {
        //Your new code here
    };
  }
}( window ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try setting your own ajax transport handler instead, take a look at the documentation for doing so here if you haven't: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxTransport/

Comment: frontsidebus, sorry, noob question, but do you know how to register a ajaxTransport?